# 'Chromedriver not in path' when using jupyter lab but works fine with vscode

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, jupyter, jupyter-lab

So as the title suggests, ive been using selenium in vscode with no trouble. I wanted to switch over to using anaconda and a jupyter lab document. When running a simple `webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()` i get the error message `Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see`. How is this possible since my chromdriver executable is located in usr/local/bin (in PATH)? I even tried to have a copy in the juputerlab files directory still no luck.

I have also tried to input the path in the brackets of Chrome() and that did not help. I am on mac FYI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chromedriver is not being found in python, windows Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405394/chromedriver-is-not-being-found-in-python-windows-anaconda)

Comment: What's the result of `os.getenv("PATH")` in the jupyter notebook? And `driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r"[path to]\chromedriver.exe")` works?

Comment: Thankyou! os.getenv("PATH") revealed that the path for my conda environment did not contain usr/local/bin. After adding the chromedriver to my condabin it worked fine.